# Ensure that video uploaded through API in youtube is public (not marked as private)

Tags: java, selenium, google-api, youtube-data-api

I have seen multiple questions from different timelines but I want to know if that's even possible now i.e. in May 2022.

Everytime I upload a video in youtube using the API i.e. google-api-services and google-api-services-youtube my video is marked as private.

Is there a way to upload the video as public while still using the youtube API's.

I suppose a selenium script is the only solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documetnation for the [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method you will find that it states.

> All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must [undergo an audit](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.

The solution is to apply for an audit once you have gone though the audit you will be able to upload public videos.